# Objects Imported from Blender to Unreal have really zoomed Materials

Tags: unreal-4, blender, 3d-meshes, materials, export

I've been learning how to use Blender for UE4. I just started figuring out how to define which sides should have materials on them. In particular, I wanted this building to have different materials for the sides and top. However, when I apply the Materials, they're very zoomed in.

[image: Zoomed in Texture]

At first I thought it was a scale issue, but Unreal supposedly converts the models from FBX units to Unreal units. The scale of the model is exactly the same as the one I made in Blender. And yet, I have this issue.

Since it seemed like a conversion of units issue, I made sure to change Blender to *also* use centimeters just like Unreal, with no scaling or conversion, and yet the issue still arises. I have tried to find a way to shrink the material, with no luck. It seems the only way to do this would be to copy the texture and modify it, but that seems unnecessary. If I wanted to use the same building with a different material, I'd need to do that over and over again.

Is there something I'm missing when Exporting from Blender and Importing into UE4?

I am using Unreal Engine 2.25.1, and Blender 2.83.1

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Searching for "unreal texture scale" or "unreal material scale" is turning up lots of results for adjusting the tiling frequency of a texture. What have you tried so far based on your research of the available tutorials?

Comment: @DMGregory As I said, I would prefer to not have to edit the texture directly. That would make it very difficult when I have many other buildings with many other materials. Yes, I could edit the material directly and change the scaling. But that would require modifying them. I wish to modify the model itself, because even with a basic plane the material is no-where close to as zoomed in.

Comment: Typically these methods do not involve editing the source texture data, which is why I recommended them. You can also adjust your UV texture coordinate unwrap in Blender, of course, but that's usually a bit more fussy than just cranking up a tiling factor.

Comment: Well, I tried this solution, but it makes the texture unusable on any object other than this. And as I said, I don't want to have to make a new copy of every texture I could use on this particular object. So if I need a certain amount of materials per building, and so many buildings, and for any other assets with this problem, I'm going to end up with a ridiculous amount of materials that are all the same, minus the UTiling and VTiling

Comment: Then it sounds like UV editing is the way to go. How have you tried laying out your UV unwrap so far? Where did you run into trouble achieving the look you want?

Comment: I have done UV unwrapping for other objects. But if I did, how would I be able to apply materials to it? I was not sure I could apply different materials to different parts if I unwrapped it, I was under the impression that was only done for objects with textures, not materials.

Comment: Your object already has a UV unwrap - it's just not one you've manually adjusted. UV-unwrapped objects can have multiple materials.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with buildings which are fairly square, instead of UV unwrapping you can try projections. https://exposeacademy.com/5-methods-of-uvw-box-mapping-in-blender-2-8x/

Try to apply the same texture in Blender, does it appear the same as it does in Unreal? I'm pretty certain as others have suggested here, that it's not an import/scaling issue, but that your UV's are way too small (which tiles the material/maps/textures in a way that makes them appear large)

Answer (score 0):

Blender's units are, by default Metric and 1.0000.  Unreal's units are, by default Metric and 0.01000.

You need to go into the unit section of your Blender information, changes the units to 0.01 then try importing.

[image: Blender 2.8 Unit Guide]